# How do you set two pairs equal to each other when one is in a vector?

Tags: c++

If you have something like `vector<pair<int, int> > one` and `one.push_back(make_pair(1,2))` if I declare another pair like `pair<int, int> thisOne` how can I make it equal to the vector element popped off of the vector?

Comment: Wait, what?  You push one on, and declare another, what is popped off the vector?  Are you popping the first pair off of the back of the vector?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Do you mean _assign_ when you say _equal_?

Answer (score 1):

To compare [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), you can just use [pair compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) operator, it has defined all the compare operators:

```
operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=(std::pair)
```

Comment: I have _never_ seen that "name" before.  "cmp" operators.  Makes sense though.

Answer (score 1):

What element popped off the vector, you haven't said anything about popping.

Maybe you want:

```
thisOne = one.back();
```